# search for a substring in where clause on an encrypted field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, encryption, postgresql-9.2

Using the attr_encryptor-2.0.0 gem with rails 3.2.11 to encrypt a text field in my postgresql 9.2.2 database.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_encrypted :description, :key => 'A secret key'
```

Before encryption I used the following where-clause to find records with description containing a given search term `s`.

```
current_user.tasks.where("description like ? ", '%'+s+'%')
```

How can I do it with encrypted description column?

I don't get how the `find_by_encrypted_<column>` works. The code below returns `nil` whether I use the entire description or a substring (of an existing record) as search term `s`.

```
current_user.tasks.find_by_encrypted_description(Task.encrypt_description(s))
```

I haven't changed the way I create records after adding encryption. Should I?

```
t = current_user.tasks.build(:description => @description)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using attr_encrypted-1.2.1 gem and the following select clause:

`tasks = current_user.tasks.select {|t| Task.decrypt(:description, t.encrypted_description).include?(s))}`

With attr_encryptor-2.0.0 gem I was getting a bad decrypt error with the same code.